# Sharing files across azure serviceFabric services

Tags: .net, azure, rpc, azure-service-fabric

What is the correct architecture/ way to share large files among services in azure service fabric. We have one stateless service(A) and one stateful service(B). A user will upload file(Say in .csv format) using stateless Service and stateful Service will process it and store the processed information in database. 
Our service A & B communicate via ServiceFabric RPC's.

To make it brief, I want to upload a file from UI, and transfer it to a separate server for processing via API calls.

Answer (score 2):

I'd consider using Azure Blob Storage for this. You can access that from anywhere, it stores data redundantly so it's safe.